# Saving checkbox checkedstatus

Tags: android, android-activity, checkbox, android-listview

Is there a way to save if the checkbox is checked or unchecked, in the cache in Android?

I have a listview and when i am clicking on an item a new activity pops up with information about that specific item. In that activity there is a checkbox, if i check it and go back to the listview and go into that listitem again, the checkbox is unchecked.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

you can use SharedPreferences or create a static boolean variable and call that value in the onCheckedChanged override method and update this value in it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can save boolean value in data storage like [shared preference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref).
Show stored checked status on pop up, save if checked status changed.